# strange behaviour of getmxrr()

Tags: php

I cant understand the reason of following behaviour of [getmxrr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php)

```
var_dump(getmxrr ( "www.yahoo.com" , &$mxhosts));  // output: boolean true  
var_dump($mxhosts);                                // output: array empty

var_dump(getmxrr ( "www.google.com" , &$mxhosts));  // output: boolean false  
var_dump($mxhosts);                                 // output: null
```

I have refered many sites mentioning that `www.` must be removed to get mx-records. But my aim is not to have mx-records but to understand the reason of this strange behaviour.
I expect some help from SO community.
Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: _Note:_ call-time pass by reference is deprecated.

Comment: It just depends on how the different domain names have been set up by their owners. They can not be expected to be the same.

Comment: @AndyGee: It would be great if you can elaborate it little.

Comment: Well lets say I own a domain name and I want my mx records to reside only on mail.domain.com then I can do this and my emails for these would be address@mail.domain.com. Most people use just the domain name as a default, some people also allow or rediect from www.domain.com to their mx records.

Comment: @andygee: **Why getmxrr returns true when $mxhosts is an empty array?** is the question. I understand that different domains can be configured differently by their owners but why getmxrr is returning true when it should return false as per [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Simple - there are just no MX records for www. subdomains in the common case. That would only make sense if you wanted to have an `whatever@www.domain.tld` address. Since there are no MX records for the hostnames that you've tried - there's nothing to return

Comment: What i am asking is **"Why one returns boolean true and other returns boolean false"**

Comment: Because the first one is a CNAME and therefore it gets resolved to its aliases first in order to get any possible MX records. When such a resolve happens - you get a result (even if it is empty) and the query is considered successful. The latter (google) only has simple A records and doesn't need further resolving - no MX records found and therefore is considered to have failed. (or at least that's the way I see it)

Comment: This is what i was expecting. I am very thankful to you for this explanation. Can you please put some URLs in your answer so that i can refer it and accept your answer?

Comment: As I noted - that is how I see it, logically. I haven't actually read about it anywhere, so I can't link to any reference on it. :)

Comment: how do you know that first one is CNAME?